# Do some game developers use tests to measure dopamine and adrenaline levels?

Tags: medical-science, videogames

A [Vice](http://www.vice.com/read/how-screen-addiction-is-ruining-the-brains-of-children) article attributes a claim to [psychologist](https://www.psychologytoday.com/experts/nicholas-kardaras-phd) and [book author](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1250097991), Dr Nicholas Kardaras:

> game developers use tests to measure dopamine and adrenaline levels in order to make video games as addicting as possible.

Is it true that some game developers do this?

Comment: Cant really answer that directly, but its unlikely because 1) Proper measurement of levels of intracerebral neurotransmiters in unpractical and 2) even if it was possible, we cant really use those as a measure of addiction, even for drugs and such.

Comment: @tpianca is correct. There's no real way to measure such things directly. Proxies can be used, such as pupil dilation, blood pressure, and heart rate. Whether those are used in the industry I don't know, I've never heard so from anyone I know, nor read about it on industry websites.

Comment: @tpianca That's what my understanding of our (inability) to measure neurotransmitters was -- which made me doubly interested in this article's claims. :( The lack of information available online though... is concerning.